# How to make properties in list into values?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to convert a list of objects into a new list where the properties are now values. I have tried to use `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to make two separate lists and then trying to combine them, without much success.

#### Example:

I want to turn:

```
[{ip: 123, name: "bob"}]
```

into:

```
[{property: "ip", value: 123}, {property: "name", value: "bob"}]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far ? Hint: you can use `object.entries` and `map`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do a for loop, go through the array and then push these new objects in a new array.

The following code should solve your issue:

```
const array1 = [{ ip: 123, name: 'bob' }];
let newArray;

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    newArray.push({
        property: 'ip',
        value: array1[i].value
    });

    newArray.push({
        property: 'name',
        value: array1[i].name
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and take the entries of the object.

```js
var data = [{ ip: 123, name: "bob" }],
    result = data.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).map(([property, value]) => ({ property, value })));

console.log(result);
```

Traditional approach with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var data = [{ ip: 123, name: "bob" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => [
        ...r,
        ...Object.entries(o).map(([property, value]) => ({ property, value }))
    ], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never heard about the flatMap method, so I will check it out :)